# Webpack fails with Node FFI and Typescript - dynamic require error

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, electron, node-ffi

In a simple Typescript program I `require` Node FFI with

```
import  * as Electron   from  'electron';`
import  * as ffi        from  'ffi';`
```

and then

```
mylib = ffi.Library('libmoi', {
  'worker': [ 'string', [ 'string' ]  ],
  'test'  : [ 'string', []            ]
  } );
```

Linking that up via webpack yields

```
WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
Critical dependencies:
76:22-40 the request of a dependency is an expression
76:43-53 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/bindings/bindings.js 76:22-40 76:43-53
```

The problem seems to be that FFI has a dynamic `require` and the fix seems to be to apply `webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin` in the `webpack.config.js` file.

This is a bit out of my reach, but an example for an Angular case is:

```
plugins: [
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        root('./src') // location of your src
      )
  ]
```

Any idea how to do this for FFI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer: [github issue comment on the Johnny-Five repo](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/issues/1101#issuecomment-213581938)

Quoting from brodo's answer, this is what you do to stop webpack getting snarled up with "bindings" and similar:

```
... the webpack config looks like this:

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/bindings$/, /^$/)
  ],
  externals: ["bindings"]
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when I do that `ReferenceError: bindings is not defined`

Comment: Webpack has changed. You will need to update the answer to fit with the new releases.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue, somehow, I managed to resolve it. I will first explain my understanding.

Main work of webpack is to bundle the separate code file into one file, by default it bundles all the code that is referenced in its tree.

Generally two types of node_modules:

1. To be used on browser side(angular, rxjs etc)
2. To be used on nodejs side(express, ffi etc)

It is safer to bundle browser side node_module but not safer to bundle node side node_module because they are not designed like that So the solution is below two steps:

1. Give appropriate target(node, electron etc) in webpack.config.js file e.g `"target":'electron-renderer'` by default it is browser
2. Declare node_side module as external dependency in your webpack.config.js file e.g.

   ```
   "externals": {
       "bindings": "require('bindings')",
       "ffi": "require('ffi')"
   }
   ```